# wiring up expandablelistview cascading checkboxes

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-view

It's been a great learning experience but i'm finally almost done with my expandablelistview adapter. It has checkboxes on the groups and childviews so, intuitively, you can disable/enable all the checks on the childviews by action of the group view checkbox. all that's left now is to make group view checkbox correspond to the children views. when i try to it crashes.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < check_states.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
        if (check_states.get(groupPosition).get(i) == false) {
            Log.d ("Meat", "Child checkboxes are not all checked!!!");
        }
    }
```

I'm very sure now that it is because I call those commands before the arraylist is finished populating --> "check_states" is an arraylist of arraylists that i use to keep the checkstates of the checkboxes.

So my question is very simply how to wait for the arraylist to finish populating before I call my commands. I've looked into what i can, but they seem a bit more involved than what this is worth. I'd rather set up a long-click menu than set up a seperate thread or spare 10 lines of code for something so meager as this.

EDIT: updated with logcat

```
10-06 19:18:08.204: W/dalvikvm(540): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.mangodeveloper.mcathomie.McatTopicsExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(McatTopicsExpandableListAdapter.java:166)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:445)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-06 19:18:08.224: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit again: Here is just about the relevant parts of the expandable adapter

```
public class McatTopicsExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

...

public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.mtopics_childview, parent, false);  
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicschildtv);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicchildchkbox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

        for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<Boolean> tmp = new ArrayList<Boolean>(children[i].length);
            for(int j = 0; j < children[i].length; j++) {
                tmp.add(true);
            }
            check_states.add(tmp);
        }

        if (check_states.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition) == true) {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
        }else{ holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                    check_states.get(groupPosition).set(childPosition, true);
                }else{ check_states.get(groupPosition).set(childPosition, false);
                }
            }   
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.mtopics_groupview, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicsgrouptv);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_group);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

        for(int i = 0; i < check_states.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
            if (check_states.get(groupPosition).get(i) == false) {
                Log.d ("Meat", "Child checkboxes are not all checked!!!");
            }
        }

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < check_states.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                        check_states.get(groupPosition).set(i, true);   
                    }       
                } else if (!isChecked)
                    for(int i = 0; i < check_states.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                        check_states.get(groupPosition).set(i, false);          
                    }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }); 

        return convertView;
    }

    //  additional components
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> check_states = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>(children.length);

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should add the stacktrace with the exception from the `logcat`. What makes populating a list of list with `boolean` values so time consuming?

Comment: and how about, boolean allChildBoxesChecked = !check_states.get(groupPosition).contains(false); This will not solve your problem, though. please post logcat and code

Comment: There. i updated it with logcat. I have reason to believe that it must be some millisecond difference time issue cause if i place the code right after the arraylist population method, it works without a hitch. thanks for that elegant tidbit, though, Tamir.

Comment: is this: if (check_states.get(groupPosition).get(i) == false) { line 183 in McatTopicsExpandableListAdapter? if so, it seems that the array is completely empty (size 0)

Comment: where do you place it if not after the arraylist populatoin method?

Comment: yes. that is line 183. I place it the getGroupView of the my expandable list adapter. the arraylist population sequence is in my getChildView of the expandable adapter. but this code isn't going to be useful in childview when replace the meat log with my real intentions. perhaps the way is to combine both methods in some boolean method. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. keeping in mind that my goal was a cascading chain with checkboxes, i finally figured out what i was doing wrong. the reason my arraylist wasn't filled by the time i saw the expandablelistview was because it defaulted collapsed and I placed the instantiation in the getChildView, which was not being called yet. So moving it to the getGroupView code block fixed that. But to get group checkboxes working like they should, I needed a new (much smaller) arraylist just for those group list checkboxes so that their states would persist. Then I set wired check box events accordingly. Just something i thought was worth noting was that calling notifyDataSetChanged() worked best in click listeners or event changed listerners because if it was left out in the open or some conditional statement then one runs the risk of having it being called extraneously, which was locking up my expandablelistview. Below is important parts of the revised code and i'll change the subject to accurately reflect the answer since this question went in a different direction.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> child_check_states = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>(children.length);
ArrayList<Boolean> group_check_states = new ArrayList<Boolean> (groups.length);

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    CheckBox checkbox;
}

public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.mtopics_childview, parent, false);  
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicschildtv);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicchildchkbox);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

    if (child_check_states.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition) == true) {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);   
    }else{ holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                child_check_states.get(groupPosition).set(childPosition, true);
                if (child_check_states.get(groupPosition).contains(false)) {
                    group_check_states.set(groupPosition, false);
                }else{
                    group_check_states.set(groupPosition, true);
                }
            }else{ 
                child_check_states.get(groupPosition).set(childPosition, false);
                group_check_states.set(groupPosition, false);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }   
    });

    return convertView;
}

public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    fillChildArraylists();
    fillGroupArraylist();

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.mtopics_groupview, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mtopicsgrouptv);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_group);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

    if ((group_check_states.get(groupPosition)) == true) {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                for(int i = 0; i < child_check_states.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                    child_check_states.get(groupPosition).set(i, true);
                    group_check_states.set(groupPosition, true);
                }
            } else {
                for(int i = 0; i < child_check_states.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
                    child_check_states.get(groupPosition).set(i, false);
                    group_check_states.set(groupPosition, false);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private void fillChildArraylists () {
    for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        ArrayList<Boolean> tmp = new ArrayList<Boolean>(children[i].length);
        for(int j = 0; j < children[i].length; j++) {
            tmp.add(true);
        }
        child_check_states.add(tmp);
    }
}

private void fillGroupArraylist () {
    for(int i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        group_check_states.add(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the length of a different array... Change your loop condition to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < check_states.get(groupPosition).size(); i++) {
    if (check_states.get(groupPosition).get(i) == false) {
        Log.d ("Meat", "Child checkboxes are not all checked!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: sadly that didn't work, but i think you've shown me that all along i've been working with something close to but not exactly the correct variables

Comment: I admit I'm not certain what you are trying to do, I simply read the logcat and corrected the error. `check_states.get(groupPosition)` still has a size of 0. However I don't think I provide any more specific help without seeing more code.