# working with ExpandableListActivity with checkbox

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-checkbox

I am using ExpandableListActivity and the child row each has a textview and checkbox within it. 
I am using SimpleCursorTreeAdapter for binding data. Problem here is that when i select a checkbox and scroll down and again come back, that checkbox unselecting. Or other issue when i select checkbox some other checkbox also selecting. I couldn't figured out why this is happening. Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: First read my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803064/android-expandable-list-view-onclicklistener-for-buttons-within-the-child-with/12803670#comment17326017_12803670

then view my code here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761200/wiring-up-expandablelistview-cascading-checkboxes/12761572#comment17244569_12761572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happens because of your get view mathode in you adapter use this link may you solve your problem.

[link for study](http://www.androtips.com/2012/03/enable-button-inside-list-item.html)

Comment: I found one strange thing. If i disable checkbox click and then if I click on anywhere in child item of a group. checkbox is getting selected and its keeping checkbox state properly. No caching issue. But when i make checkbox clickable and if i select checkbox. Caching issue coming, means if i scroll down and come again, checkbox getting deselected. or random checkbox getting selected.

Comment: sohan are you perform opration on check box in your CustomAdapter